# Erlang print 2 list

Tags: list, functional-programming, erlang

I have 2 list:

```
 List1 = [1,2,3].
 List2 = ["asd", "sda", "dsa"].
```

How can i print this list in following turn:

1 asd
 2 sda
 3 dsa

Thank you.

Comment: Mentioning the reason for such print wouldn't hurt.

Comment: There is a fun argument-swapping solution to this one: `[io:format("~p", [X]) || X <- merge(List1, List2)]` where `merge([], L) -> L; merge([H|T1], L2) -> [H | merge(L2, T1)].` (not tested).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
1> lists:zipwith(fun (X1, X2) -> io:format("~p ~p ", [X1,X2]) end, List1, List2).
1 "asd" 2 "sda" 3 "dsa" [ok,ok,ok]
2>
```

Answer (score 6):

sometimes it's better to reinvent the wheel. in case of erlang - just to understand recursion, tail calls and how to work with lists.

```
f([], []) -> 
    ok;
f([H1|R1], [H2|R2]) -> 
    io:format("~p ~p", [H1, H2]), 
    f(R1, R2).
```

Comment: @shk: And since either of the lists contain the same number of elements, the head of the first clause can safely be written as `f([], _)`, where `_` is the "don't care" variable, which ignores the value.

Comment: @Yasir Arsanukaev: It depends of context and expected strictness of function. More strict version can sometimes catch some errors. There is also more benevolent version `f([H1|R1], [H2|R2]) -> 
    io:format("~p ~p", [H1, H2]), 
    f(R1, R2); f(_, _) -> 
    ok.`

Comment: @Hynek: Heheh indeed; quite forgot that feature. The latter clause works as "catch all" (if I don't confuse the terms), and will be called in all other cases (lists either empty or of different size). Our functions are of "defensive programming" though. Thanks for notice. :-)